# Remove none values from dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like :

```
    Country Name    Income Group
 1  Norway          High income
 2  Switzerland     Middle income
 3  Qatar           Low income
 4  Luxembourg      Low income
 5  Macao           High income
 6  India           Middle income
```

i need something like:

```
    High income     Middle income   Low income
1   Norway           Switzerland     Qatar
2    Macao              India         Luxembourg
```

I have used pivot tables :
df= df.pivot(values='Country Name', index=None, columns='Income Group')
and i get something like :

```
    High income     Middle income   Low income
1   Norway           none            none
2    none           Switzerland      none
 .
 .
 .
```

Can someone suggest a better solution than pivot here so that i don't have to deal with none values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to introduce a new column `index` whose values are `groupby/cumcount` values. `cumcount` returns a cumulative count -- thus numbering the items in each group:

```
df['index'] = df.groupby('Income Group').cumcount()
#   Country Name   Income Group  index
# 1       Norway    High income      0
# 2  Switzerland  Middle income      0
# 3        Qatar     Low income      0
# 4   Luxembourg     Low income      1
# 5        Macao    High income      1
# 6        India  Middle income      1
```

Once you have the `index` column, the desired result can be obtained by pivoting:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country Name': ['Norway', 'Switzerland', 'Qatar', 'Luxembourg', 'Macao', 'India'], 'Income Group': ['High income', 'Middle income', 'Low income', 'Low income', 'High income', 'Middle income']})

df['index'] = df.groupby('Income Group').cumcount() + 1
result = df.pivot(index='index', columns='Income Group', values='Country Name')
result.index.name = result.columns.name = None
print(result)
```

yields

```
  High income  Low income Middle income
1      Norway       Qatar   Switzerland
2       Macao  Luxembourg         India
```